# Setting debug configuration for maven+jetty+eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, maven, maven-jetty-plugin

I have created a web app using maven in eclipse. I am using jetty for running the app.
I am able to run the app using the maven jetty plugin. But I am facing difficulty while debugging the app -
The steps that i have followed to setup debug settings are from the below link
http://www.clickonchris.com/2010/05/configuring-jetty-maven-and-eclipse-together-with-hot-deploy/

I can run the app at port 8080 and it keeps on Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 4000. For debugging i have given port 4000. But when i start the debugger in eclipse it gives me a window with following error -
"Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
Connection refused: connect"
Can some one help me out in resolving this issue for debugging the app.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Issue resolved....all the steps given in the above mentioned links are working well...i faced issues because after starting the debugger i got the error message as port 4000 was already in use...

Answer (score 43):

Set MAVEN_OPTS using -

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"
```

Then start jetty using -

```
mvn jetty:run
```

Start remote debugging from your fav IDE on port 8000

Comment: should be `mvn jetty:run`

Comment: or simply `mvnDebug jetty:run`

Answer (score 8):

Here's a quick workaround. I was battling with this problem also and after a while I achieved a lazy solution.

I use Eclipse Indigo with m2eclipse. I created a new Run Configuration: Right-Clicked the project in Project Explorer ->  Run As... -> maven build. Then I defined the necessary maven commands/goals to run the project with jetty straight from Eclipse.

Finally I just ran the newly created configuration in Debug mode and got debug working. This probably messes up something else(?) but works as a quick workaround.

Comment: Whoops sorry, I realized just now it was already resolved. I should buy new glasses.

Comment: hey its ok...got chance to know about your work around thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by h3xstream in one of the comments, you can run using `mvnDebug jetty:run`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Pascal Thivent in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2935475/1346996) answer, since [Maven 2.0.8](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-2105) one can use `mvnDebug` in the following way:

```
mvnDebug jetty:run
```

This will start maven in debugger mode on port 8000.