# Maven3 - Debug main source code only

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, maven-3, surefire

I have a standalone maven project where I run a java program using org.codehaus.mojo exec plugin.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>java</executable>   
                    <argument>-classpath</argument>
                    <classpath>
                    </classpath>
                    <argument>com.abc.Main</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I also have test cases under src/test/java directory, which I can debug using surefire plugin. But, I can't debug the main code using mvnDebug directly by running com.abc.Main class(though this looks straightforward by attaching Eclipse workspace project in Debug mode on a port being listened by mvnDebug). I'm wondering if we can use surefire plugin directly on main code to debug?

**UPDATED**

I use eclipse Kepler version with installed "Maven Integration for Eclipse" plugin

Comment: Usually, you know you're not doing a good job explaining and illustrating your problem when nobody replies... Show some code, draw a picture, explain a bit more about your problem. I also have a problem: some of my code doesn't do what I expect. Do you know what's wrong? :)

Comment: Okay, I updated this as you suggested. Yes, I do know what's wrong, that's why I'm here on this site :)

Answer (score 2):

Try running Maven like this:

```
mvn -Dmaven.surefire.debug="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=9001 -Xnoagent" clean install
```

And use the remote debugger to connect to port 9001. This will allow you to put breakpoints in your test code.

Comment: Thanks, here your command runs the test case classes, which I do not want. I want to run just the main program in debug mode. I tried your command by replacing "clean install" with "exec:exec". It just ran my program without debugging it. With your command I can debug my main source code "through" test cases as starting point, which I already know and mentioned in my post.

Comment: In that case try debugging the `exec:exec` by passing in the JVM debugging options described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935375/debugging-in-maven.