# How to debug a maven project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, maven

I am trying to debug following maven project in Eclipse:
https://code.google.com/p/cloudscale/

I followed the instructions of RickHigh (found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19986408/3014213) and when I write mvnDebug exec:exec in Terminal the lines

```
Preparing to Execute Maven in Debug Mode
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
```

appears and after starting the Remote Java Application in Eclipse, the project is started BUT it does not hold on breakpoints...

Any ideas, what could go wrong?

Comment: This worked for me http://www.homik.de/think/index.php/2008/07/31/debugging-maven-projects-with-eclipse/

Comment: Have you tried putting method breakpoints instead of normal breakpoints?

Comment: @webdev
I already tried the solution described there, but it still doesn't work

Comment: @wjans
good idea, but doesn't work

Could it be, that it is not possible, because the classes aren't testclasses?

Comment: Can you also show us how you have configured the maven plugin and your remote debug options?  I suppose it might be a forked process and that you should connect your debugger that the forked process rather than the maven process itself.

Answer (score 1):

When you install [m2e plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) in Eclipse, it will show you a link in Console view to automatically connect debugger (i.e. create remote debugger launch configuration) to your process when it spills "Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000" message to the console. So, your debugger is basically one click away.

Answer (score 0):

The debugger may be connected to the wrong JVM - not the one created by `exec:exec`. Try remote debugging like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22367089/1878731