# How to execute a specific plugin/Mojo from a pom.xml programmatically?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I'm the author of one of the Maven plugins (not Apache/Codehaus, completely indie). Sometimes I get support requests or test cases where I'd really need to debug the execution of my plugin with an existing `pom.xml`. Basically the test cases I get are sample/test project (`pom.xml` with `src/main/resoures`, `src/main/java` and so on).

What I need is a way to:

- Load an existing `pom.xml`.
- Find a specific execution of my plugin there (usually it's the only one).
- Get an instance of `MyMojo` - fully initialized/condigured, with all the components and parameters corectly injected.
- Execute `MyMojo`.
- What's important is that test projects are separate projects, I don't want to copy them into the Maven module of my plugin.
- I'd like to be able to do this without remote debugging.

By debugging I mean to be able to set and halt on breakpoints (also conditional), step in/out/over on the source code.

Ideally I'd like to be able to `executeMyMojoFrom(new File("pom.xml"))` - for instance in a JUnit test or a `main` method of some class. (I can supply `groupId`, `artifactId` etc. All other definitions should just be loaded from that `pom.xml`.)

**How can I achieve this?**

---

What I've tried so far:

- `Debug As...` on `pom.xml` in Eclipse - does not work well enough (source code not found, breakpoint don't work as its not a Java project context)
- Maven Embedder/Invoker solutions - spawn things in separate processes via CLI. Forget breakpoints, no debugging.
- Remote debugging with `mvnDebug` and then remote debugging from Eclipse as suggested by Pascal Thivent [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935375/debugging-in-maven/19986408#19986408). This is so far the best option. However, remote debugging means starting `mvnDebug` separately, and there's also not guarantee that the JARs I have in Eclipse are exactly the same that `mvnDebug` is using. So there's a certain distance here.
- [`maven-plugin-testing-harness`](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-testing/maven-plugin-testing-harness/getting-started/index.html) - I actually thought this this will do the task. But first I was jumping through hoops for a few hours just to make it start. All of the important dependencies are "provided" so I first had to figure out the right combination of versions of these artifacts. And then - only to discover that [`AbstractMojoTestCase`](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-testing/maven-plugin-testing-harness/getting-started/index.html)  only works within the plugin module you want to test. Probably I was mistaken when I thought that `maven-plugin-testing-harness` was a testing harness for Maven plugins. It seems that it's a testing harness for the plugin from that plugin's module. Which is not illogical but does not help my case. I'd like to test my plugin in *other* modules.

So right now I've got the best results with the remote debugging solution. But what I'm looking for is really something like `maven-plugin-testing-harness` but not hardwired to the plugin module. Does anyone happen to have a hint, if such a method exists somewhere in Maven artifacts?

To be even more specific, I'd like to write something like:

```
 public void testSomething()
        throws Exception
    {
        File pom = getTestFile( "pom.xml" );
        assertNotNull( pom );
        assertTrue( pom.exists() );

        MyMojo myMojo = (MyMojo) lookupMojo( "myGroupId", "myArtifactid", ...,
                                             "myGoal", pom );
        assertNotNull( myMojo );
        myMojo.execute();

        ...
    }
```

Compare it to the `MyMojoTest` [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-testing/maven-plugin-testing-harness/getting-started/index.html) - it's almost there. Should just not be hardwired into the `mymojo` Maven module (as it is in `maven-plugin-testing-harness`).

---

**Update**

Few answers to the questions in comments:

> You mean you don't want such a test class, i.e `MyMojoTest` to reside inside the same project as the `MyMojo`, i.e your plugin project? Why is that?

Exactly. I want to debug the plugin execution in an existing Maven project, I don't want to move that project to my plugin project *first* to be able to run a test. I want to be able to test/debug an existing project. Ideally, I'd just need to add `my-maven-plugin-testing` dependency and subclass `MyMojoTest` in the project's src/test/jaca. This would be a good instrument to debug executions. Dragging the target project into my Mojo project ist just too much overhead - and mostly these aren't really the test cases I want to keep long-term. I hope, this answers, why.

> Anyway, it's merely a convention to keep the `project-to-test/pom.xml` inside the `src/test/resources` of your plugin module, not a rule...

My problem is not the location of the `pom.xml` of the `project-to-test`, that is easily configurable. My difficulty is that `maven-plugin-testing-harness` is is somehow hardcoded to be in the Mojo's project. It uses the `pom.xml` of the Mojo, looks for other special files/descriptors in the containing project. So I somehow can't use it in a non-Mojo project, or can I? This is my question.

> And I'm not sure why `Debug as...` didn't help you...

Not sure either, but (1) breakpoints did not work and (2) the source code was not "attached" for some reason.

Comment: I would suggest to take a deeper look here: https://github.com/ifedorenko/com.ifedorenko.m2e.mavendev BTW: Which plugin do you develop?

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you, I will take a look. I develop the [`maven-jaxb2-plugin`](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin).

Comment: @khmarbaise I've checked it, this is way too `m2e`-centric, I can achieve the same type of debugging with the remote debugging. What I'd like to have is a possibility to execute a mojo from a specific `pom.xml` in a test. But thank you for the hint anyway.

Comment: You mean you don't want such a test class, i.e `MyMojoTest` to reside inside the same project as the `MyMojo`, i.e your plugin project? Why is that? Anyway, it's merely a convention to keep the `project-to-test/pom.xml` inside the `src/test/resources` of your plugin module, not a rule, just like creating the `MyMojoTest` in the `src/test/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/my` directory is.

Comment: And I'm not sure why `Debug as...` didn't help you - it's always worked for me whenever I wanted to debug my plugin or any maven plugin for that matter.

Comment: @lexicore Well, I never meant that you have to put the `project-to-test` inside your plugin, in fact I have always been suggesting the opposite. But it looks like keeping the `project-to-test` out isn't just enough - you're looking for a generic solution to invoke a `mojo` (and possibly do more) from a test case outside of the test harness. If so, have you looked at the source code of the [harness](https://github.com/apache/maven-plugin-testing/blob/trunk/maven-plugin-testing-harness/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/testing/AbstractMojoTestCase.java) to see how it is done?

Comment: Or [mojo-executor](https://github.com/TimMoore/mojo-executor) for that matter?

Comment: @mystarrocks Ok, then I did not get your point right. Yes, I was (of course) looking into the code of the `harness`. It does not look impossible to execute mojos from other `pom.xml`s but looked like a fair amount of work to make it work. I thought I'd ask before doing that...

Comment: @lexicore On the other hand, I've used `mojo-executor` extensively and I do think it will fit your need.

Comment: I'm just flinging this against the wall here, but perhaps you could fire up an entire Maven instance and call into it:   http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.5/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/Maven.html#execute(org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequest)

Comment: @user3120173 I'll give it a try but from the API perspective this looks like a CLI invocation. But I'll check.

Comment: @mystarrocks Why don't you post your hint about the `mojo-executor` as an answer? This looks pretty close to what I need. I think I'll be able to combine it with the `maven-plugin-testing-harness` to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `Debug as` didn't work for you as well as it should, you can try to use the `mojo-executor` with a bit of work.

https://github.com/TimMoore/mojo-executor

This is how you would execute the `copy-dependencies` goal of the `Maven Dependency Plugin` programmatically:

```
executeMojo(
    plugin(
        groupId("org.apache.maven.plugins"),
        artifactId("maven-dependency-plugin"),
        version("2.0")
    ),
    goal("copy-dependencies"),
    configuration(
        element(name("outputDirectory"), "${project.build.directory}/foo")
    ),
    executionEnvironment(
        mavenProject,
        mavenSession,
        pluginManager
    )
);
```

The `project`, `session`, and `pluginManager` variables should be injected via the normal Mojo injection. Yes, that means this should be executed from the context of another maven plugin. Now that I think about it, whether this would help you in any way is still a question because this still relies on injection of such components by the underlying `plexus` container.

My original idea was though to have you build a maven plugin that would invoke your `jaxb2` plugin thru the `mojo-executor` like above, then serialize the `mavenProject`, `mavenSession`, `pluginManager`, i.e, all the `plexus` injected components and then use those objects to invoke your `jaxb2` plugin in future from a standalone class without the plugin that you built.