# Debugging in maven with mvnDebug command

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, tomcat7

I read this:
[Debugging in Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935375/debugging-in-maven)

I'm running intellij remote debug and maven for a service I'm trying to debug.

I'm running

```
mvnDebug tomcat7:run
```

Which gives me the following result

```
Preparing to Execute Maven in Debug Mode
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
^Ctai-m:sb-api-internal-server tai$ m
```

My problem is that I want to change the port easily. I know that I can go into the pom.xml file and change it or that I can do the following in:

mvnDebug.bat

```
@REM set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000
```

but I want to be able to specify my port on the command line. Is there any way to do this? I want to be able to debug multiple services on different addresses running at once and am under the impression that it would be a hassle to have to set and reset the debug file setting for each one.

A friend said it should be possible but I can't seem to find a solution.

Essentially Im looking for a way to easily switch the port a service is running on hopefully without modifying a file multiple times as I launch multiple services. Otherwise Is there another solution you can thing of? Ex having the first debug instance running on one port and then having the second on another (hard coded)?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wow, Maven makes this difficult. Setting `-Xrunjdwp` in `MAVEN_OPTS` won't work, because `mvnDebug.bat` adds its own afterward, which will override `MAVEN_OPTS`. I would copy `mvnDebug.bat` to `myMvnDebug.bat` and comment out the line `set MAVEN_DEBUG_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000`. That way you can set `MAVEN_DEBUG_OPT` on the command line before running it.

```
C:\somewhere>set MAVEN_DEBUG_OPT=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8001
C:\somewhere>myMvnDebug.bat
```

Comment: This is works. It's hacky but it appears to be the only solution. Additionally you can do this and set multiple command line settings( ex debug on 4000, 5005, 6000) each as different terminal commands. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I changed @set MAVEN_DEBUG_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000

to

@set MAVEN_DEBUG_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=%MAVEN_DEBUG_PORT%

in mvnDebug.cmd then either set MAVEN_DEBUG_PORT in env variables or locally with set @set MAVEN_DEBUG_OPTS=8001 before you call mvnDebug xxx:run (I'm using Jetty)

Answer (score 0):

Another answer under the question you mentioned is https://stackoverflow.com/a/2935474/19955141 . I think that solution match your need, just use exec goal in exec plugin:

```
mvn exec:exec -Dexec.executable="java" -Dexec.args="-classpath %classpath -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1044 com.mycompany.app.App"
```

You can modify the address value to set port.