# How to run remote debugging on maven embedded-glassfish server?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, glassfish

My current embedded-glassfish plugin

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <app>${basedir}/target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.${project.packaging}</app>
    <port>8001</port>
    <contextRoot>services</contextRoot>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I've started embedded glassfish server with `mvn embedded-glassfish:run` and tried to run remote debug on port 8001 unsuccessfully with the following error...

> Error running local glassfish debug: Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8001): java.io.IOException "handshake failed - connection prematurally closed"

What do I need to do to enable remote debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run the embedded Glassfish Server with following Maven-command:

```
mvnDebug embedded-glassfish:run
```

Then connect remote debugger to port 8000.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction! However, I can't find any reference of port 8000 in settings.xml even though it's default debug port.

Comment: Unfortunately seems to be a bit more complicated to change the debug port; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310760/debugging-in-maven-with-mvndebug-command