# Error or not error? What does this unreadable line in Maven install output mean?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, maven-install

The `Maven` `install` output in `Eclipse` writes several of such lines:

```
[ERROR]  50% 21/31 build modules 52% 22/31 build ....
```

I am putting here only part of one of these lines, they are extremely long. You can see the whole output on the [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx_xGpPBzN0kaW5HckxmZlZuUDA/view?usp=sharing). Look out for [ERROR] there.

I don't like to see these error messages not knowing what they are about. What if they signalize on something really bad? Or simply bad? Or they are merely Maven's Halloween jokes? I am afraid not.

All projects of the workspace seem to be `installed` OK

```
[INFO] ca-sp .............................................. SUCCESS [ 24.287 s]
[INFO] ca-cm .............................................. SUCCESS [ 21.186 s]
[INFO] ca ................................................. SUCCESS [ 20.438 s]
[INFO] ca-tests ........................................... SUCCESS [  1.340 s]
```

#### But

after that, at the end, I see:

```
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP Can't allocate jvmti memory, jvmtiError=JVMTI_ERROR_INVALID_ENVIRONMENT(116)
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP on getting class status, jvmtiError=JVMTI_ERROR_WRONG_PHASE(112)
```

The next lines are in red:

```
JDWP exit error JVMTI_ERROR_WRONG_PHASE(112): on getting class status [util.c:1285]
JDWP exit error JVMTI_ERROR_INVALID_ENVIRONMENT(116): Can't allocate jvmti memory [util.c:1799]
ERROR: JDWP unable to dispose of JVMTI environment: JVMTI_ERROR_INVALID_ENVIRONMENT(116)
```

These fatal errors are known as eclipse bugs [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=432718). I am afraid, you won't help me with them. When the maven makes the install, these end errors can appear or not, with the probability about 2/3. But those strange unreadable [error] lines appear always. I hope, understanding them could save me from the errors coming at the end.

Eclipse:
Version: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)
Build id: 20171005-1200

Java:
jdk-8u152-windows-x64.exe

Comment: Did you run mvn in debug mode as well it exposes more output. i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935375/debugging-in-maven

Comment: Definitely merely Maven's Halloween jokes :)

Comment: @HRgiger It is an excellent idea, I was foolish to forget to use it, but it does not brings any real help this time - the strange lines have no [debug] lines around them, only [info] ones. And these are about some normal and quiet things, not about errors.

Comment: Woah, you have some output there!  You are right I couldnt see anything as well

Comment: Update with the eclipse version and java version used please. And this is exclusive to eclipse run? I mean when you run `mvn clean install` on command line on your project, you aren't seeing them, right?

Comment: @HRgiger You could look for [ERROR] there.

Comment: @nullpointer I am sorry. Edited, added. As for standalone Maven that is what i am trying just now.

Comment: Seems just like some progress indicator which some -maybe lazy- coder has set to ERROR level because for some reason did not want to configure logging. Did you find [this](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6988950) already? It is old but maybe regression or somehow related.

Comment: @pirho Thank you! That really seems that way! Could you write this as an answer, please - I will mark it so surely. And the fatal errors are the separate consequence of an unstable bug in Eclipse/mavenPlugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long log lines starting like

> [ERROR] ????????????  0% compile?????????????????????? 10% 0/1 build modules

are most probably progress indicator logs which have been set logged with wrong level (and wrong way?) in development phase and never changed to appropriate level when releasing.

Hardly developer has thought that it is actually an error that module gets build but has forgotten to change the level to `[DEBUG/INFO]`.

Character `?` marks non printable character which is always `0x08` = `BACKSPACE`. Why there are such chars and why all this stuff is in a single line is a mystery. Maybe someone needs this kind of output for some analysis?

If you remove those chars and and add line feeds to appropriate places you will get stuff like (my guess in in comments not necessarily correct):

```
[ERROR] 0% compile
10% 0/1 build modules    // build for module 1 started
70% 1/1 build modules    // build for module 1 near to finish
40% 1/2 build modules    // build for module 2 started
70% 2/2 build modules    // build for module 2 near to finish
50% 2/3 build modules    // build for module 3 started (and so on)
70% 3/3 build modules
54% 3/4 build modules
```

Interesting detail is also that there is exactly the same amount of backspaces **before** each readable part of log, for example (i have added line feeds but spaces are in text):

```
????????????
  0% compile               // two spaces before text
??????????????????????
 10% 0/1 build modules     // one space before text
```

Coincidence?

Comment: For me the main result is that that message is definitely not connected to the Eclipse/plugin bug that unstably appears at the end. A negative result is a result, too.

Comment: _A negative result is a result, too_ Yes, that is called research :)

Comment: Oh! I have looked into Eclipse log, there is written not only messages, but who left them, too. And those long messages are left by maven plugin!

Comment: @Gangnus What maven plugin is that? Is the format as unclear as in log file in you posted?

Comment: It is an interesting problem by itself. I will make another question from that in about 2 hours. No time just now, sorry.