# How do I debug a maven project through UNIX mac terminal?

Tags: java, maven, debugging, unix

Seems like jdb doesn't work with maven. Everything I look up online is talking about debugging maven through Eclipse or IntelliJ. I'm literally just making this project through UNIX with maven. Normally I could debug using println or something but this is my first multi-threaded project and I have no idea where to start. Just want to step through the program line by line.

Comment: [Debugging in Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935375/debugging-in-maven)

Comment: I saw that post and unfortunately don't seem to understand any of the responses fully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use `mvnDebug` to execute instead of just `mvn`, this will run in remote debugging mode. Then connect to the port from another terminal window while the program is running with jdb `jdb -attach 8000` (this is the default port, it should print in the console what it's actually using)

Comment: So when it says "Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000", I should enter the command "jdb -attach 8000"? It doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: What output do you get from the 2 terminal windows? It sounds like the first one is starting the debugging session, is it terminating before the connection?

Comment: Sorry I misread your original post and was only using one terminal window. Works now, thanks!

Comment: My original post didn't contain the info about the separate terminal, I realised that and updated afterwards. My apologies for not giving a comprehensive answer on the first try. Glad to have been of help in the end.